# Get the time from {date}T{time}Z

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I want to get the hour and the minute from this string: `2013-09-12T11:00:00Z`. How can I do this with `date()`? `date('H:i', strtotime('2013-09-12T11:00:00Z'))` prints `13:00` and `date('H:i', '2013-09-12T11:00:00Z')` prints nothing.

Comment: Simple answer is: because given time is in UTC timezone (Z parameter is UTC); and you are GMT+2 (Sweden). So 11:00 +2hour is 13:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use [gmdate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) instead:

> Identical to the `date()` function except that the time returned is
>   Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

So `gmdate('H:i', strtotime('2013-09-12T11:00:00Z'));` should do the trick. )

Answer (score 1):

I'd use PHP's [`DateTime`](http://php.net/date) (available on 5.2.0+) class for this:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2013-09-12T11:00:00Z');
echo $datetime->format('H:i');
```

prints

```
11:00
```

**[Demo!](https://eval.in/48103)**

Comment: Tell me, why exactly it's _best_ to use it?

Comment: @raina77ow: there are multiple reasons why, but you cannot name one reason why `gmdate` and similar functions are better.

Comment: In fact, I can: one does not use cannons to shoot the flies. Have you analyzed PHP source code (and [this file](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/date/php_date.c) in particular), you'd have seen that `DateTime` constructor basically uses the same facilites that 'similar' functions do - but does a lot more as well in process of creating an _object_. Sometimes it's useful, of course, but something tells me that's not the case in this particular situation.

Comment: `One does not use cannons to shoot the flies.` This is just funny (btw. a lot of people allover the world are fishing with grenades hehe). You cannot say that `DateTime` is hard-core method for interacting with datetimes and the `strtotime()` and similar functions are for newbies. Maybe the source code for `DateTime` isn't as pretty as `gmdate()`, but if you run your code and @Amal's 100k times, there is no difference in time consumption. Like I already said today somewhere, this debates over `strtotime()` vs `DateTime` is like parsing HTML debate with `regex` vs. `DOM`.